# difference between "nice" and "as nice"

Tags: as

> Some aren't **as nice.**

I don't understand subtle difference btw nice and as nice.
In context, I'm pretty sure the meaning are not much different from "Some aren't nice." But he said "as nice."

Is there any difference or intense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As" before an adjective indicates a comparison, either explicit or implicit.

"Not as nice" is an implicit comparison: either *not as nice [as something I've already talked about]* or *not as nice [as I expected/might have expected]*.

In a particular instance there might be litte difference between *not nice* and *not as nice*; but *not as nice* is explicit that it is comparing, even if the the standard of comparison is unstated.